# Table printer with sort

Tags: python

I wanted to create a simple table that will print and sort. This what I have:

```
 from tabulate import tabulate
 def main():
 # Create a list of strings
 tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'gooses']]

  # Sort the list
   tableData.sort()

  # Print the table
  print tabulate(tableData)

  # Call the main function.
  main()
```

Is my syntax correct? Are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using tabulate, you might want to be able to manually print tables, because this allows you a greater degree of freedom in how you want the table to appear - this will require a lot more effort though!
I find the python string.format() method very useful for this sort of task, here is an example of a table printer I programmed using .format():

```
Table=[['Name','Age','Level','Score'],['Tom','15','5','999'],
   ['Bob','105','7','2']]

LongestItem=0
for List in Table:
    for Item in List:
        if len(Item)>LongestItem:
            LongestItem=len(Item)

for List in Table:
    for Item in enumerate(List):
        List[Item[0]] = '{:{}}'.format(List[Item[0]],LongestItem)

for Index in range(len(Table)):
    print(' '.join(Table[Index]))
```

If you wanted, you could easily adjust the table to have column and row lines, centre aligned records, 0 padded data etc. - This gives you more freedom than tabulate.

Comment: Also note that some of your indentation appears a little off, but that may be to do with stack overflow's code blocks messing up your indentation.